# How to read the _io.TextIOWrapper data?

Tags: python

I'm trying to open a .dat file using `f1= open('rec_1.dat')` I get <_io.TextIOWrapper name='rec_1.dat' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>. I then change the instruction to `f1= open('rec_1.dat', encoding = 'cp1252)` and I get the following error 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 1396: character maps to .

If I change the encoding to 'ISO-8859-1' I can then use `file_contents = f1.read()` But I get complete garbage like ïÿéÿðÿéÿòÿèÿñÿèÿíÿèÿ and so on. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: I would expect a file with a .dat extension to be much more likely to contain binary data of some sort, rather than anything human-readable.  What is the exact source of this file?

Comment: What do you *expect* the file contents to look like, and *why*? In particular, why should it be something *other than* "complete garbage like ïÿéÿðÿéÿòÿèÿñÿèÿíÿèÿ and so on"?

Comment: @jasonharper I got the data from https://physionet.org/content/ecgiddb/1.0.0/ . It's supposed to contain ECG data.

Comment: What are you hoping to *do with* the data?

Comment: @corleone_chris right, so what were you expecting that data to look like when interpreted as text???

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I have seen other samples of ECG data and they are usually just the voltage levels at a particular moment in time. Most of the time it's just one really long list of basic integer values so I assumed that getting like ïÿéÿðÿé was probably not correct.

Comment: The file almost certainly contains the raw binary representations of those integer values, consecutively. Those aren't going to look meaningful under any text encoding. The website you linked mentions "12-bit resolution", so it's possible that the values are even bit-packed (such that some of the bytes of the file are part of two different sample values).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Is there any way to be able to interpret those binary representations without having any previous knowledge on how the data was stored?

Comment: No, you cannot meaningfully interpret data without knowing (or slowly and painfully working out) how it was intended to be interpreted.

Comment: The files appear to be in a format called WFDB.  Some info can be found here: https://physionet.org/physiotools/wag/signal-5.htm . You *can't* do anything with the .dat files by themselves, you have to read the corresponding .hdr file (which is human-readable text) to find out the exact format of the binary data.

Answer (score 0):

The file in question is not using the CP1252 encoding. It's using another encoding. Which one you have to figure out yourself.

Open the file in Notepad++ if you are using that editor. In the bottom right it will tell you the current file encoding. In the top menu, next to "View" locate "Encoding". In "Encoding" go to "character sets" and there look for the encoding that you need.

Comment: How do you know which encoding is the correct one? I got the data from https://physionet.org/content/ecgiddb/1.0.0/ and from what I can tell the source is Russian but that's not an option.

Comment: @corleone_chris what *are you expecting*? Why do you think this is supposed to be interpreted as *text*?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga On the website where I got the data you have the option to see the data in a table and it shows up with three columns; Time ECG I and ECG I filtered. Under the two ECG columns, it contains voltage levels.

Comment: @corleone_chris ok, I'm not sure that answers my question. Unless you were expecting it to create that visualization by opening it as a text file? Again, *what text are you expecting*. The data seems to be raw ECG recordings, not text. Interpreting it as text will always be junk.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I wasn't expecting any particular text. I just wanted to be able to get the data into something that seems more human-readable

Comment: I don't know the correct encoding but you can figure it out by your own attempts (I have shown one)